# Difference between two timestamp in Hive through query

Tags: hive, hiveql, cloudera-cdh

I have a hive table  with following columns

```
    session     Timestamp
    1           2018-05-18T00:00:00.000Z
    1           2018-05-18T00:01:00.000Z
    1           2018-05-18T00:02:00.000Z
    1           2018-05-18T00:03:00.000Z
    2           2018-05-18T00:05:00.000Z
    2           2018-05-18T00:10:00.000Z
    2           2018-05-18T00:15:00.000Z
```

For each session, I want to find the difference between the first timestamp and last timestamp, in seconds

Hence my output will be like this

```
    session     Period
    1           180
    2           600
```

The 1st difference, `180 (seconds) = 2018-05-18T00:03:00.000Z - 2018-05-18T00:00:00.000Z`

The 2nd difference, `600 (seconds) = 2018-05-18T00:15:00.000Z - 2018-05-18T00:05:00.000Z`

Both session and Timestamp is in string.

I am trying to convert string timestamp into unix timestamp using this command, however I am not successful

```
    select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(Timestamp, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")) AS NEW_TIMESTAMP from TBL;
```

Answer (score 1):

unix_timestamp converts a string to timestamp (seconds), so you just need to use this function and substract the min from the max :

```
select 
max(unix_timestamp(Timestamp, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))
-
min(unix_timestamp(Timestamp, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))
from TBL
group by session_id
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF